# How to pass array property in model Asp.net Core in HttpGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have `Asp.Net WebApi 2 project, Now converted into Asp.Net Core 2.0`

HttpGet method with array property not able to bind model.

the model comes null in Asp.net Core 2.0 
(using swagger to test)

Any changes required?

```
public class Customer
{       
    public string name { get; set; }
    public new string[] systemId { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult RetrieveData(Customer filters)
{
// code
```

In Asp.net WebApi2 It was working properly, but in Asp.net Core values are not able to bind, values are null.

If change it to [HttpPost] it will work fine but why not with [HttpGet] as working like ASP.Net WebApi2.

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. include example request.

Comment: @Neo, how do you test the request? I think you should do: GET YourApi/RetrieveData?name=SomeName&system_id=1&system_id=2

Comment: yes i will try that way thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net core changed it default binding to `FromBody`. So your signature should now be:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult RetrieveData([FromBody]Customer filters)
{
// code
```

And send it as body.

You could also use the data-attribute: `FromQuery`.

you can read this article: https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/required-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

cheers!

Comment: a GET request has no body

Comment: ahh, correct, misread it! but the `FromQuery` would still apply

Comment: You are close to the answer. review this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding and reformulate your answer.

Comment: both properties are empty? how does your url look like?

Comment: http://localhost:54844/api/v1/RetrieveData?pageIndex=1&pageSize=1&systemId=BuildID%3D16&name="test"

Comment: I'm confused :( what exactly missing here? any help?

Comment: looking at your class. why do you have `new` for the string array? shouldn't be this `public string[] systemId { get; set; }`? Not sure if `new` would cause any trouble.  Could you try the name without the quotes? Let me setup a project!

Comment: hmm, I have exactly your code and it works like a charm... let me look into it a bit further

Comment: I'm testing using swagger